# How to turn resources.getStringArray to a mutable array?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to be able to make my resources dynamic so that I can remove and add strings to it, for this I need to get the array programatically which I've done. However, I can't seem to figure out how to turn it into the correct array for this.

`var array=  resources.getStringArray(R.array.paintings)`

I want to assign this array to a MUTABLE array.

However

```
var mutableArray: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList<String>()
mutableArray = array <------- Doesn't work
mutableArray.removeAt(2)
```

How do I make it mutable?

Comment: `toMutableList` ? In java I would do `new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { } ));`

Answer (score 1):

Well you have multiple options:

1. You can use kotlin MutableList instead of ArrayList:

code:

```
val mutableList = array.toMutableList()
mutableList.removeAt(2)
```

2. If you want to use ArrayList you can convert Array to ArrayList using two methods:

.

- I- The first one is by adding all array elements to ArrayList using
  `addAll()`:

code:

```
val mutableArray: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList<String>()
mutableArray.addAll(array)
mutableArray.removeAt(2)
```

- II- The second one is by converting Array to List then converting
  that List to ArrayList:

code:

```
val mutableArray: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList(array.toList())
mutableArray.removeAt(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Your `array` is already mutable, as it is an Array.
your `mutableArray` is a MutableList, and not an array.

However, this does not make your resources dynamic. `resources.getStringArray(R.array.paintings)` loads your resources into an aray; changing that array does not change your resources but only that specific copy of it in memory.

If you want to have a persistant memory that you can read from or write to, you can do that with, for instance, [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) or [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore)